# Ordered DynamoDB Operations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm currently building a system that needs to take in a series of DynamoDB operations from multiple sources, and execute them in the order received.

Originally, I was thinking of sending all operations through a FIFO SQS queue and have a lambda function remove the messages and then execute them in DynamoDB. The problem with this, however, is there's no way to guarantee that only one instance of the function will run, and thus two lambda functions running at the same time could execute two operations out of order.

I'm currently stumped, and I would love any guidance on how to implement this?

Comment: Are you saying you have multiple lambdas listening to the same stream or queue?

Comment: Just one lambda, but I need to guarantee that only one instance of it will be running at a time.

Comment: Answer is - don't. For sequences of operations you should use something like Kinesis Streams.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html). You can trigger lambda on each DDB operation of insert/save/update/delete. You are guaranteed to receive updates on single row in ordered fashion for processing.

> A DynamoDB stream is an ordered flow of information about changes to items in a DynamoDB table. When you enable a stream on a table, DynamoDB captures information about every modification to data items in the table.

The above solution works for single table operations. From cross table, you need to a higher level solution to manually get updates in order/correct sequence.